# Service to service communication via api gateway(NestJs Microservice)

Tags: nestjs, microservices, api-gateway

In a microservices architecture, the API Gateway is the single entry point for all clients. Now I have Api-gateway communicating with all the other services(auth-microservice) and return respons to the client. I need to somehow emit/send from auth-microservice and acknowledge from api-gateway.

Is it possible? if yes, how?

## api-gateway main.

```
async function bootstrap() {
  const app = await NestFactory.create(AppModule, {
    bodyParser: false,
  });
const port = process.env.PORT || 3333;
  await app.listen(port);

}

bootstrap();
```

## Auth module.

```
@Module({
  imports: [
    ConfigModule,
    ClientsModule.register([
      {
        name: 'AUTH_MICROSERVICE',
        transport: Transport.KAFKA,
        options: {
          client: {
            clientId: 'auth',
            brokers: [process.env.SERVICE_KAFKA_BROKER],
          },
          consumer: {
            groupId: 'auth-consumer',
          },
        },
      },
    ]),
  ],
  providers: [AuthService, GoogleStrategy],
  controllers: [AuthController],
  exports: [AuthService],
})
export class AuthModule {}
```

## Auth service of api-gateway.

```
@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements OnModuleInit {
  constructor(
    @Inject('AUTH_MICROSERVICE') private readonly authClient: ClientKafka
  ) {}

  onModuleInit() {
    this.authClient.subscribeToResponseOf(topics.USER_CREATED.toString());
  }

 createUser(user: User) {
const createUserRes = await this.authClient.send(
      topics.USER_CREATED,
      JSON.stringify(user)
    ).toPromise();

    return createUserRes;  //here i got respons from auth microservice.

  }

}
```

## Auth microservice controller.

```
@Controller()
export class AppController {
  @MessagePattern(topics.USER_CREATED)
    async handleUserCreate(@Payload() data: any) {
      // process data and return.
  }
}
```